# Stripe account creation fails on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I coded up a function to let e-commerce site members to create their own Stripe accounts for them to be able to receive payments through Stripe. I followed an online tutorial but it's not working so far (results in calling `flash[:danger] = "Unable to create Stripe account!"` from the stripe_controller.rb). The codes and problems are below.

app/controllers/stripe_controller.rb

```
class StripeController < ApplicationController
  # Create a manage Stripe account for yourself.
  # Only works on the currently logged in user.
  # See app/services/stripe_managed.rb for details.
  def managed
    connector = StripeManaged.new( current_org_person )
    account = connector.create_account!(params[:country], params[:tos] == '1', request.remote_ip)

    if account
      flash[:success] = "Managed Stripe account created!"
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Unable to create Stripe account!"
    end
    redirect_to org_people_stripe_settings_path
  end
end
```

app/services/stripe_managed.rb

```
class StripeManaged < Struct.new( :org_person )
  ALLOWED = [ 'US', 'CA', 'TW' ] # public beta
  COUNTRIES = [
    { name: 'United States', code: 'US' },
    { name: 'Canada', code: 'CA' },
    { name: 'Taiwan', code: 'TW' }
    # { name: 'Australia', code: 'AU' },
    # { name: 'United Kingdom', code: 'GB' },
    # { name: 'Ireland', code: 'IE' }
  ]

  def create_account!( country, tos_accepted, ip )
    return nil unless tos_accepted
    return nil unless country.in?( COUNTRIES.map { |c| c[:code] } )

    begin
      @account = Stripe::Account.create(
        managed: true,
        country: country,
        email: org_person.email,
        tos_acceptance: {
          ip: ip,
          date: Time.now.to_i
        },
        legal_entity: {
          type: 'individual'
        }
      )
    rescue
      nil # TODO: improve
    end

    if @account
      org_person.update_attributes(
        stripe_currency: @account.default_currency,
        stripe_account_type: 'managed',
        stripe_user_id: @account.id,
        stripe_secret_key: @account.keys.secret,
        stripe_publishable_key: @account.keys.publishable,
        stripe_account_status: account_status
      )
    end

    @account
    binding.pry
  end

  def update_account!( params: nil )
    if params
      if params[:bank_account_token]
        account.bank_account = params[:bank_account_token]
        account.save
      end

      if params[:legal_entity]
        # clean up dob fields
        params[:legal_entity][:dob] = {
          year: params[:legal_entity].delete('dob(1i)'),
          month: params[:legal_entity].delete('dob(2i)'),
          day: params[:legal_entity].delete('dob(3i)')
        }

        # update legal_entity hash from the params
        params[:legal_entity].entries.each do |key, value|
          if [ :address, :dob ].include? key.to_sym
            value.entries.each do |akey, avalue|
              next if avalue.blank?
              # Rails.logger.error "#{akey} - #{avalue.inspect}"
              account.legal_entity[key] ||= {}
              account.legal_entity[key][akey] = avalue
            end
          else
            next if value.blank?
            # Rails.logger.error "#{key} - #{value.inspect}"
            account.legal_entity[key] = value
          end
        end

        # copy 'address' as 'personal_address'
        pa = account.legal_entity['address'].dup.to_h
        account.legal_entity['personal_address'] = pa

        account.save
      end
    end

    org_person.update_attributes(
      stripe_account_status: account_status
    )
  end

  def legal_entity
    account.legal_entity
  end

  def needs?( field )
    org_person.stripe_account_status['fields_needed'].grep( Regexp.new( /#{field}/i ) ).any?
  end

  def supported_bank_account_countries
    country_codes = case account.country
                    when 'US' then %w{ US }
                    when 'CA' then %w{ US CA }
                    when 'IE', 'UK' then %w{ IE UK US }
                    when 'AU' then %w{ AU }
                    when 'TW' then %w{ TW }
                    end
    COUNTRIES.select do |country|
      country[:code].in? country_codes
    end
  end

  protected

  def account_status
    {
      details_submitted: account.details_submitted,
      charges_enabled: account.charges_enabled,
      transfers_enabled: account.transfers_enabled,
      fields_needed: account.verification.fields_needed,
      due_by: account.verification.due_by
    }
  end

  def account
    @account ||= Stripe::Account.retrieve( org_person.stripe_user_id )
  end
end
```

The problem should be that `def create_account!` in the stripe_managed.rb returns `@account` as `nil`. Therefore I suspected `Stripe::Account.create` was failing. I thought of 3 issues here.

1. I currently live in Taiwan, which Stripe is yet to support, and use Stripe Japan's account to manage the platform. The tutorial I referred to was from North America so it was originally looking at only the U.S. and Canada, then I added Taiwan in the hash `COUNTRIES`. But because Stripe is not supporting Taiwan, I proceeded with `Stripe::Account.create` with "U.S." as the located country.
2. Because of the issue 1, I suspected the ip address and the selected country (U.S.) got a discrepancy. And it returned `[7] pry(#<StripeManaged>)> ip => "::1"`. I googled but couldn't see what getting "::1" means in my context.
3. On the console, I executed `[9] pry(#<StripeManaged>)> Stripe::Account.create(managed: true, country: country, email: org_person.email, tos_acceptance: {ip: ip, date: Time.now.to_i}, legal_entity: {type: 'individual'})` and got `Stripe::InvalidRequestError: Missing required param: type.` I couldn't find referable examples online but this looked like the most suspicious issue to me.

It would be great if anyone could help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to create a Custom account via the API but you're sending the wrong parameter. When you create an account this way you should pass `type: "custom"` instead. The parameter `managed` has been deprecated since [2017-05-25](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2017-05-25) and is not supported on newer accounts.

Your code should be:

```
Stripe::Account.create(
    type: "custom",
    country: country,
    email: org_person.email,
    tos_acceptance: {
      ip: ip,
      date: Time.now.to_i
    },
    legal_entity: {
      type: 'individual'
    }
  )
```

All API requests made to Stripe either return a valid resource or raise an exception if an error happens. Your code needs to at least log those errors while you're debugging so that you can easily track an issue with Stripe. You can also see all your API requests directly in the Logs in the [dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs). This would have let you see the parameters sent and what the API returns easily.

Comment: I got it fixed!!! And yes, I found how to seethe logs in the dashboard. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Koopajah, this question has been already closed with success but can I ask you another question? The question is how to add codes to pass an external account info in the controller. It seems external accounts were not required when the tutorial was made. If it's not appropriate to ask this here, I will create a new question.

The log in the dashboard is; "external_accounts": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/external_accounts"
  },

Comment: you should pass a bank account token in `external_account`: https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_account-external_account and you can create the token with Stripe.js: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#collecting-bank-account-details

Comment: Thanks! I successfully added the external account. Thanks a lot